# Email Validation Without using regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to write email validation,  two or more emails are separated by semi colon.I want server side validation/client side validation both. without use of regex. If email is not valid it should show error to user.

I want to write in controller

xyz.abc@mail.com
xyz12.ab12c@mail.com;aqwq123bc@mail.com
It should not accept any special character other than .(dot) in 1st part of the string.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include relevant code and what you've tried.  We are happy to help but we are not a code writing service.  Also, is there are reason you don't want to use Regular Expressions?  They are very powerful and pretty universal so unless there is a great reason, you should consider using it otherwise you'd never be able to check that the emails are valid because of all the permutations.

Comment: You got our permission to write that code. If that is not enough please [edit] post to clarify what exactly blocking you from writing it. Make sure to demonstrate why existing information was not helpful (like "I searched https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+sheck+string+ascii and still don't understand how to check if character is not special because …")

Comment: *"It should not accept any special character other than .(dot) in 1st part of the string."* is not enough rules to validate an email address, I believe. Write out the rules, then for each rule write a validation step. Then put those steps in a function that takes a string and returns a bool.

Answer (score 0):

If you can include `System.Net.Mail`, then you can use the following, but I ***really*** don't recommend it. Unless you are literally unable to, **please use regular expressions for this, it's much nicer.**

```
try {
    MailAddress m = new MailAddress("somemail@mail.com");
} catch {
    //invalid
}
```

Comment: But i want to validate multiple email address with semi colon separated. And if it is single email no semicolon.

Comment: Just split your emails into an array with `.Split(';')` and then loop over it.